# Adding a custom page to Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, setup, waik

I am trying to figure out if its possible to add a custom page during an OEM Windows 8 installation that asks the user if he/she wants to enroll in a service. The page will have some information about the service, the EULA of the service and a checkbox to determine if the user wants to enroll or not.

I've been reading about Windows image customization using [WAIK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [WSIM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824929.aspx), but the resources are scarce and I only managed to find articles talking about how to make the installation automated and omit the user from changing settings during installation which is exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Anyone know how I can achieve this or maybe reference an article or guide that might help me achieve this.

Regards

Comment: Easiest way is to write your own GUI and schedule it via `start /wait mygui.exe` from the setupcomplete.cmd in your $OEM$ folders.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger I am looking to integrating the steps to look like one smooth operation from start to finish. Your recommendation will open a new dialog/windows on top of the setup UI, am I right?

Comment: nope, the setup ui will already be completed by then and I should add `cannot be edited`.  The app would appear on a blank background as the next to last thing to run before the first logon occurs.